# Python regex lookbehind inconsistency?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

When I run the following code:

import re

```
s = 'baaaad'

l = re.findall(r'((a)(?=a))', s)
print l
for elem in l:
    print ''.join(elem)
```

I get the output:

[('a', 'a'), ('a', 'a'), ('a', 'a')]
aa
aa
aa

which is as expected.   But when I try the corresponding strategy for lookbehind ie:

```
s = 'baaaad'

l = re.findall(r'((?<=b)(a))', s)
    print l
for elem in l:
    print ''.join(elem)
```

I get:

[('a', 'a')]
aa

I was expecting to get:

[('b', 'a')]
ba

Why this (to me) unexpected behavior?  If I am doing something wrong, what is it?  And how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to think that one of the groups in the output is from `(a)`, and the other is from the lookahead or lookbehind. That's not the case. One of the groups is `(a)`, and the other is from the parentheses surrounding your entire regex:

```
 v    v not these
((?<=b)(a))
^         ^ these
```

The lookahead **does not** match `a`, and the lookbehind **does not** match `b`. They match a *position* in the string after which an `a` occurs, or before which a `b` occurs. They don't match any actual characters. Thus, both your regexes only match `a`, with restrictions on what might come before or after, and both capturing groups in both regexes only capture `a`.

Comment: Just to mention, there is no issue in capturing characters within a lookaround `((?<=(b))(a))`

Comment: Let me understand.  So you are saying that even the "correct" answer for the lookahead is because of some other reason?

Comment: @whirlaway: Yup. You had two bugs whose visible effects happened to be exactly opposite, so it happened to produce the output you wanted. When you changed things a little, the effects of the bugs stopped being opposite.

Comment: Thanks!   I now am wondering how exactly I can get the right answers in the two cases..